# How to deploy a nodejs express app for production on Apache server?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, deployment

In angular, i used

> npm run build:prod

to build app for production. In the end i get bunch of files outputed in the dist folder.

But with nodejs how can i build for production and upload to some server. Let's say i use Apache then what shoud i upload from nodejs source? Is it the whole folder that is used in development mode?

Does anyone have experience with nodejs deployment knowing the right way to deploy nodejs application?

Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to go based on what kind of server you're pulling the files to. Apache is your http server, which will come into play when you're setting up for a user to actually hit your page as a website.

By moving your files to a server as in CentOS, Ubuntu, etc. you need to also copy your node.js files. Not sure which server you're using. There are multiple ways to set this up. Here's a link by Ditital Ocean they have different server instructions: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#install-pm2

Also here's an rpm method for CentOS 7: 
https://github.com/bbc/speculate/wiki/Packaging-a-Node.js-project-as-an-RPM-for-CentOS-7